# Prove that $\mathbb R^n$ is both closed and open

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I would like to show that $R^n$ is both closed and open **only** using these two definitions:

> $A⊆R^n$ is **closed** when it contains all its boundary.
>
> $A ⊆R^n$ is **open** if it does not contain any point of its boundary.

Is this because the set of boundary points of $R^n$ is the empty set?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.

Comment: But how can $\emptyset \in R^n$?

Comment: $\emptyset \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, not as an element.

Comment: So contains means $\subset$ and not $\in$. I thought it was the other way around. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as subset of itself is (all the closures are taken within $\mathbb{R}^n$, naturally)
$$\partial\mathbb{R}^n=\overline{\mathbb{R}^n}\cap\overline{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\mathbb{R}^n}=\overline{\mathbb{R}^n}\cap\overline{\emptyset}=\overline{\mathbb{R}^n}\cap\emptyset=\emptyset.$$
Therefore, $\mathbb{R}^n$ contains none of its boundary points, but also all (zero) of its boundary points and is, by your definition, open and closed. So yes, you are right.

Note that this did not require any more than the metric structure of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The same argument will work for any metric space.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct and the same argument works in any topological space.